# Oracle ATP autonomouse db - how to encode special characters

Tags: oracle-autonomous-db

I have an ATP cloud database where I am using the apex_web_service.make_rest_request procedure to make a REST request.  The service is failing on a particular JSON payload that contains an & (ampersand) in the data. The service provider told me to run it through a url encode utility, but I don't know what utilities are available in ATP databases to do that.  Hoping someone can help.

```
 {
   "Id" : "123",
   "Name" : "THELMA & LOUISE",
   "state" : "CA"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Joe - You shouldn't need to escape the "&" character, your PL/SQL code just gets the data as-is.
So, a couple of things:

- If the data is already encoding, make sure that you're using the correct "Content-Type" header (e.g: "text/plain") when using the [MAKE_REST_REQUEST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/MAKE_REST_REQUEST-Function.html#GUID-C77BB45A-8968-470C-8243-BADB63743DE9) Function.
  Example:

  ```
   declare
       l_result clob;
   begin
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete();
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name  := 'Content-Type';
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'text/plain';

   l_result := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
   p_url => 'http://us.music.yahooapis.com/ video/v1/list/published/popular',
   p_http_method => 'GET',
   p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('appid:format'),
   p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('xyz:xml'));
  ```

  end;
- If you really need to escape it, then you can use the [apex_json.stringify](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/STRINGIFY-Function-Signature-1.html) function.

Please provide an example of your code to help you better.

Comment: Thank you Monica.  It turns out the ampersand was fine.  There was another record that had a CR/LF (carriage return and line feed).  I was able to remove those and the REST service worked fine.

Comment: Great to hear that!